# Python: Line Split Value Error?

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7.3 btw

Hi all,

I have a little problem. The problem is that I keep running into trouble with the starred line below. (Sorry, kinda new to Python)

So here is my code so far:

```
with open('parsedChr','w') as fout, open('heartLungClassU.gtf','r') as filein:

    average = 0
    difference = 0
    position = ''
    bp = 0

    for line in filein:
      **chrom,cuff,exon,start,end,dot,sign,dots,gene,tranid,exonid,rest = line.split('\t',11)**
      ## notice 12 variables here so I tried to unpack with value 11

    ##more code after
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 11, in <module>
    chrom,cuff,exon,start,end,dot,sign,dots,gene,tranid,exonid,rest = line.split('\t',11)
ValueError: need more than 9 values to unpack
```

I don't understand why though -- note that there are 12 variables I am splitting the line into. Why would python complain about needing more than 9 values to unpack? I've had code before where I had to split into 6 variables and so used 5 in line.split (5 cuts into 6 pieces, as I understood it), but I don't understand why similar logic doesn't work here.

EDIT: here is a portion of the file:

```
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    14765607    14765689    .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000018";  transcript_id   "TCONS_00001260";   exon_number "1";    oId "CUFF.68.1";    class_code  "u";    tss_id  "TSS40";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    14766604    14767199    .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000018";  transcript_id   "TCONS_00001260";   exon_number "2";    oId "CUFF.68.1";    class_code  "u";    tss_id  "TSS40";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    21156530    21156632    .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000028";  transcript_id   "TCONS_00002433";   exon_number "1";    oId "CUFF.88.1";    class_code  "u";    tss_id  "TSS69";
```

EDIT: Meh. Figured it out. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: little problem and such huge code is posted.

Comment: Can you show us the file. How it looks like?

Comment: I would guess that one of your rows is missing a couple values -- consider `a,b,c = 'foo bar'.split(' ',2)`

Comment: You can also remove that `blah blah blah`. Its not part of the code right?

Comment: @RohitJain here is the link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108419362/file.gtf

Comment: I tried with that file and didn't encounter any errors with the call to `split`.

Comment: Are you sure that the lines are always tab separated?  Is it possible that some of your tabs got replaced by spaces?

Comment: @mgilson yeah I'm pretty sure. Let me use sed to replace all blank spaces with \t and see what happens then just to make sure though.

Comment: @Joe -- Then you might get errors with "too many values to unpack", but at least it'll tell you something ...

Comment: @Joe -- In the future, you may want to consider using `line.split(None,11)`.  This will split the string into 12 segments splitting at any consecutive strings of whitespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see what the exact line number where the error is do this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(filein):
    try:
        chrom,cuff,exon,start,end,dot,sign,dots,gene,tranid,exonid,rest = line.split('\t',11)
    except ValueError:
        print "ValueError on line", i+1
        print "line", repr(line)
        raise
```

In your comment you provided a [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108419362/file.gtf) to your text file.  I don't find any line with less than 11 tabs:

```
>>> for i, line in enumerate(urllib.urlopen('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108419362/file.gtf')):
...     if line.count('\t') < 11:
...         print i+1, repr(line)
...         break
...
>>>
```

Double check that you are really opening the file you think you are opening.

Comment: @Joe.  Use the second version.  It will tell you the line number and print the `repr` of the line, which shows the tabs as `\t`.

Comment: Now it returns... nothing. Haha. I'm not sure what's going on, but I guess I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @Joe:  Double check that you are really opening the file you think you are opening.

Comment: No, definitely opening the right file. It worked after I used sed to replace all ' ' with \t... I guess I missed something somewhere. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It means that your line does not contain enough (in this case at least 9) tabulator characters so that `split()` call would fill all the variables with the splitted values.

The following code will produce the same error:

```
s = 'a b'
x, y, z = s.split(' ') # the result is ('a', 'b') but we have 3 variables
                       # on the left side of the expression.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to figure out which line is causing this... even though as far as I can tell I can't find any lines that don't have 9+ tabs in them...

Comment: You're welcome! Give a try to the code with try..except as @Steven Rumbaiski explained.

Answer (score 2):

it means the line splits into only 9 values:

example:

```
>>> a,b,c='foo bar'.split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

you can add an `if` condition to handle this:

```
if len(line.split('\t'))>=11:
```

Comment: Almost identical to my comment above.  Striking.

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying -- but I combed through the file and I can't find any lines where that is the case... weird.

Comment: @Joe Why not just post a portion of your file?

Comment: you  should post the file content in the question then.

Comment: Just edited the post so it contains a small portion of the file.

Comment: @Joe try something like `line.split('\t')[:11]`